# Issues with multipart Post

Tags: windows-phone-7, post, multipart

I am using HttpWebRequest for Multipart Post to upload images in the form of byte array to server and I am supposed to receive a json string containing details of the post in response. But in contrast I am getting just a response code "OK" as the response irrespective of the success or unsuccess of the post. Can anybody help me out for this.

I using following code for the post.

```
Dictionary<string, object> postParam;


public void SubmitPost()
    {

        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);
        myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }


    public string url
    {
        get
        {

            return "URL";

        }
    }



    string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();


    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);


        writeMultipartObject(postStream, postParam);
        postStream.Close();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);

    }
    string res;
    private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();

        res = response.StatusCode.ToString();

        response.Close();

    }
```

the value of res is always "OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read response from `streamRead`. `StatusCode` is just says that data has been uploaded.